# which regex pattern sets the matcher to stop at first string instance?

Tags: java, regex, string

how do i match the first string?

e.g.

txt: `now>=2017-03-07-00&now<=2017-04-05-00`

patterns `".*?now>=(.*)-00"`

gives me: `2017-03-07-00&now<=2017-04-05`

instead of: `2017-03-07`

Comment: Use `now>=(.*?)-00` with `Matcher.find()`.

Comment: Matcher `.*?now>=(.*)-00` won't work for two reasons: first, it is greedy, which can be fixed with `.*?now>=(.*?)-00`. In addition, you'll need something for tailing characters, so total would be `.*?now>=(.*?)-00.*`